# Nullpointer exception in hashtable traversal

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, hashtable

I am creating a hash table in java, and need to do some analysis. One of my analysis tasks is to compare the number of values that hash into a single value.

Given a prime number (arbitrary decision), I fill the hash table with random numbers. The amount of randoms I generate is equal to 0.8*primeNumber. I am using separate chaining to handle hash clashes. Although the array in the hash table stores nodes, each node can point to another node (so it is really an array of linked lists).

My problem is when I am trying to traverse the bucket (our array holding nodes) to see how many nodes in the tree in total hash to a single value. So, for example, if our function is value%prime, and our prime is 5, and we generate the numbers {10, 5, 2, 7, 15, 4, 23}, then we will have 10, 5, and 15 hash into a single value (0, because 5%5 is 0, likewise for 10 and 15}, and also 2 and 7 will hash into the same value (5%7 = 2) thats a total of 3 + 2 or 5 things hashing into 1 value (basically, the problem is to find the number of hash collisions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because:

```
public Node getNext() { return nextNode; }
```

at one point returns **null**. So when you issue **h.hasNext()** and h is null, you'll get the NullPointerException. Without altering your core logic, the simplest fix is a null check:

```
while (h != null && h.hasNext()) {
```